# Given an already defined template function, is it possible to overload it with another template function without it being ambigious?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

There is a library that defines a template function to ensure that it is overloaded or specialized for any type that you use, otherwise it will result in a static assert failure.

I want to replace it with another template function that works for a subset of the types that can be accepted by the original.  Is it possible to do so without modifying the source code in the library?

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

// used for static_assert
template <typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

namespace OWNER { namespace LIB_API {
  // function defined in some other library:
  template <typename T>
  void fn(T const&)
  {
      static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "Must override or specialize.");
  }
}}
// defined types in my source:
struct should_work { /*...*/ };

struct should_not_work { /*...*/ };

// specify a function with parameter
void this_fn(should_work const &) { /*...*/ }

// my test for a function with the signature this_fn(T const&)
template <typename T>
using has_fns = std::void_t<decltype(this_fn(std::declval<T>()))>;

namespace OWNER { namespace LIB_API {
  // my generic override for a subset of types in T
  template <typename T, typename = has_fns<T>>
  void fn(T const&) { /*...*/ }
}}

void test()
{
    fn(should_work());      // Should run my generic code.
    fn(should_not_work());  // Should cause a static assert failure
}
```

This code of course doesn't work and will result in an ambiguous call to `OWNER::LIB_API::fn(T&)` error.  Is it possible to make it unambiguous?  Note that my code and the library calls `OWNER::LIB_API::fn(T&)`.

Comment: Inherit the library class?

Comment: @SvSv There is no library class.  Only a free function, which is called by the library and by me.  `should_work` and `should_not_work` are my own classes.

Comment: Why dont you create a class with some function pointers? That would work, I guess.

Comment: @SvSv, a class with a function pointer?  Some sort of proxy?  No, I thought of that.  It has to be direct use of my classes.

Comment: It is interesting that this library does this.  I don't think that this use case was thought of when it was designed, and was expecting that overloading or specialization of specific types would be the only way to go.  If it didn't exist, it would just cause an error which might be harder to read, but allow what I want to be done to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (probably the only way actually) to do what you want is to overload `fn` such that it accepts a special kind of wrapper.

```
template< class, class = std::void_t<> >
struct has_fns : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct has_fns<T, std::void_t<decltype(this_fn(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type { };


template <class T, class has = has_fns<T>>
struct fns_wrapper
{
   T const& t;
   fns_wrapper(T const& t) : t(t) {
       static_assert(has::value, "Wrapper only works for types with this_fn");
   };
};

namespace LIB_API {
  template <class T>
  void fn(fns_wrapper<T> wrapper) { this_fn(wrapper.t); }
}
```

Then

```
    fn(fns_wrapper(should_work()));        // runs generic code.
//  fn(should_not_work());                 // fails with static assertion
//  fn(fns_wrapper(should_not_work()));    // fails with another static assertion
```

Comment: Yeah. I have this already, but I need it to take the original object. Not a wrapped one. Seems that I'm going to have to do a hybrid where it is you're answer and have a specific function that forwards to it. `auto LIB_API::fn(should_work const& x) { return fns_wrapper<should_work>(x); }`.